# How to find Printrboard pin numbers in Marlin

Tags: marlin

I'm looking for a Printrboard  board image with the pin numbers labeled. Specifically for Rev. F.

Specifically, I'd like to know what each pin on the `EXP1` and `EXP2` correspond to numberwise within Marlin.

The `pins.h` file for the Printrboard Rev. F doesn't include any other files and doesn't indicate what pin number corresponds to which part on the board...

There is this [google sheets file](http://slamdanz.com/at90usb1286_Marlin_PinMapping.html) which provides some of the information.

[image]

This image has the categories of each pin labeled. But I'm looking for where the pin numbers on the board correspond to the numbers in Marlin, similar to this image for the MKS Gen L:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked https://reprap.org/wiki/Printrboard ? You can find the schematic with pin numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As FarO suggested, from github:[Printrbot](https://github.com/Printrbot)/[printrboard](https://github.com/Printrbot/printrboard)/[revF2](https://github.com/Printrbot/printrboard/releases/tag/revF2) (via [RepRapWiki - Printrboard](https://reprap.org/wiki/Printrboard) - [Revision History](https://reprap.org/wiki/Printrboard#Revision_History)), the EagleCAD board layout and schematics are contained in the `printrboard-revF2.zip`:

- `Printrboard.sch`
- `Printrboard.brd`

This is the EagleCAD schematic:

[image: Printrboard-revF2 schematic]

EagleCAD board layout

[image: Printrboard-revF2 board layout]

Not quite the *annotated* diagram that you were after, unfortunately, but it might help.

---

There are a couple of configuration files on [KevinOConnor](https://github.com/KevinOConnor)/[klipper](https://github.com/KevinOConnor/klipper), but unfortunately only for revisions [B to D](https://github.com/KevinOConnor/klipper/blob/master/config/generic-printrboard.cfg) (at90usb1286) and [G](https://github.com/KevinOConnor/klipper/blob/master/config/generic-printrboard-g2.cfg) (SAM3x8c)... E and F are not available.